# Replace a branch failing with another one

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have my develop branch messed up, so I have another branch which is working correctly, how can I replace my FULL develop to my new working branch? Develop has some roles and I can not push to it directly .

My status

master dead

develop dead

newbranch working

So I want this newbranch go to develop and then create a Pull request to master and put newbranch into master.

Comment: You can create a PR from "working" branch to "develop" branch.

Comment: No, because it says that there's anything to merge

Comment: That sounds strange, if there is no diff, problem may not be in the code. It may be in the inputs or some configuration that is outside your code repo.

Comment: make sure your develop is up to date locally ! use a `git pull` when on develop

Comment: then use a `git merge newbranch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this:

```
git checkout develop
git pull #just to make sure everything is up to date locally
```

then,

```
git checkout newbranch
git merge -s ours develop #this merges develop while keeping all changes from newbranch
git checkout develop
git merge newbranch
```

after this, test your code while on develop, and you are good to go!!